# Cypress | How to create a variable from network response body for OTP on login test

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-intercept

Disclaimer: I'm very new to using cypress, javascript and coding in general so please be as clear as possible as I'm still picking up some basic concepts.(I have a lot to learn and I appreciate you!).

Problem:  I'm writing a login test that requires a OTP. In the test environment, the OTP is listed as a key value in the network response body after entering UN/PW and clicking a continue button. The response looks something similar to this:

{"status":"VALID_USER","otp":"123456","maskedEmailAddress":"email@email.com","maskedPhoneNumber":"***-***-****","otacDeliveryPreference":"SMS","pinRequired":true}

so the UI flow is to enter a UN/PW > click continue (this action triggers the request) > a new page loads that asks for the one time pw listed in the response as "otp":123456

I am trying to get cy.intercept to work so I can pull out that 6 digit pin (it's unique every time), turn it into a variable to then plug into my test to successfully login

I have read so many tutorials and have kind of frankensteined together the following test, but unsurprisingly keep getting errors.

```js
context('QA login', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("https://QAlogin.com/login")  
  })

  it('should login to QA', () => {
    
    cy.get(usernameField)
      .type(username)
      .should('have.value', username); //enters username

    cy.get(passwordField)
      .type(password)
      .should('have.value', password); //enters password

    cy.intercept("POST", "/login").as("getLogin")  
      .get(loginButton)
      .click()

    cy.wait('@getLogin').then(xhr => {
      cy.log(xhr.response.body)
      const jsonResponseData = xhr.response.body
      const pinNumber = jsonResponseData['OTP'] 

      cy.get(accessCodeField).type(pinNumber)
      cy.get(submitButton).click()
    }); 
  })
});
```

I was hoping that this would intercept the request after I made that first .click() and make a variable out of the response body, and then make a variable out of the otp key value in the body. I'm not sure if this is a good approach.

Edit: I moved the .intercept based on a helpful answer, but my test fails when trying to use the pin as a variable. error msg:

"cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined"

How can I get the otp pin from the response body to save to a variable?

thank you in advance, any advice is appreciated - I'm clearly wading in waters too deep (but i'm trying!!)

Comment: This should help you with using local variables with Cypress. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196883/17917809

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the intercept listener to a position before the action that you want it to catch

```js
// set up listener
cy.intercept("POST", "/login").as("getLogin")

// trigger the POST you want listener to catch
cy.get(loginButton).click()

// wait for interception
cy.wait('@getLogin')then(interception =>
```

Comment: thanks @Ricky.Hinkley - I move the .intercept which was very helpful. I don't think my approach on how to extract data from the intercepted response body is working as the otp does not get saved to the variable I'm trying to assign it to.

Comment: Code layout needs improving, but structure is correct, must be  `const pinNumber = jsonResponseData['OTP'] ` that is wrong. Or drop body in `const jsonResponseData = xhr.response;`, hard to tell from the question.

Comment: turns out I had a typo in the url for the intercept (woof) but once I fixed that my test worked based on your answer that the intercept was in the wrong spot! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that might work better.

Note that I've used the `cy.wrap(xhr.response.body.otp).as('pinNumber')` instead of `const` variables, which I then retrieve using `cy.get('@pinNumber').then(pinNumber => {})`. This is more verbose, but it's the Cypress-recommended way of storing data from the browser for later reuse.

I'm also not chaining the login button click off the intercept command, as that's not how the intercept command is designed to be used.

```
it('should login to QA', () => {
    cy
        .get(usernameField)
        .type(username)
        .should('have.value', username); //enters username

    cy
        .get(passwordField)
        .type(password)
        .should('have.value', password); //enters password

    cy
        .intercept("POST", "/login").as("getLogin");

    cy
        .get(loginButton)
        .click();

    cy.wait('@getLogin').then(xhr => {
        cy.log(xhr.response.body);
        cy.wrap(xhr.response.body.otp).as('pinNumber');
    });

    cy.get('@pinNumber').then(pinNumber => {
        cy
            .get(accessCodeField)
            .type(pinNumber);
    });

    cy
        .get(submitButton)
        .click();
});
```

Comment: This is great James, thank you. Do you have any recommended articles on best cypress practices for these kinds of suggestions so I can learn more about them?

Comment: Unfortunately using an alias does nothing special in this case, since `pinNumber` is directly used inside the callback.

Comment: @TesterDick - are you suggesting that wrapping the otp as an alias doesn't serve useful in this case? I'm confused on why it would be better to make the pin number a variable vs. an alias. FWIW- I tried James' suggestions and they do work, but I'm trying to understand why one way is better than the other.

Comment: It also works if you do not set an alias the problem is the order of commands as Ricky Hinckly stated, and James has followed that advice but is wrongly saying the fix is to add an alias.